# Logarithmic Function With Range [0,1] for domain between [0,n]

Tags: functions

I'm looking for a function that has logarithmic like behavior for a set of input ranging from [0,n]. The range of the output should be [0,1].

$\lim_{x\to 0} = 0$

$\lim_{x\to n} = 1$

Basically, I'm trying to have values near n be very close to 1, and slowly fall off towards zero as input gets closer to 0. Value for $n/2$ for example would be greater than $1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x) = \displaystyle\frac{\log(x+1)}{\log(n+1)}$ should do the trick.

Comment: Beautiful. Any input on how to adjust the curve to alter how quickly it increases as $x$ increases? i.e. some knobs I can play around with? Oh, maybe I can just play with base of log to do that.... let me experiment

Comment: Doh, of course changing log base does nothing because change of base formula results in base change being meaningless. Embarassing how much I've lost since I did my B.S. in Physics!

Comment: Aha, adding a coefficient in front of $x$ and $n$ that is less than one works.

Comment: Is there a term meant to describe how quickly a logarithmic function approaches it's upper limit?

Comment: Logarithmic functions don't have upper limits (only the bounded interval forces the function to be bounded), so there isn't a name for that. You can also look at functions of the form $f(x) = (x/n)^b$ for real numbers $0<b<1$ if you want different shapes.

Comment: Yes of course, that makes complete sense. Thanks for your help Greg!